# Is it possible to use a referred used (from referral) for ldap authentication?

Tags: authentication, ldap, openldap

I have a setup with 4 LDAP servers, and I'd like to use the same credentials to authenticate and administrate all of them.

What I had in mind was to use one of the servers to host the credentials, and then setup a referral in the other servers to the server hosting the credentials.

I've done some tests and I didn't managed to authenticate on one of the servers using the "referred" credentials. I believe this is normal but I'd like to be sure I didn't miss anything.

Lastly, if referral do not work, is syncrepl a good candidate to achieve what I'm trying to do ?

Thanks for your help.
Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When an application receives an LDAP referral and follows it, it opens a new connection which needs to be authenticated. In other words, if you need to authenticate against all directories, you need to have the credentials in all directories. Replication is the way to make sure the data is identical on all directories.